# Using a home partition that already has data

Tags: windows, linux, partitioning

This is the thing: I want to install Ubuntu side by side with Windows. I have a big NTFS partition that has a folder with the same name as my username (let's say "joe"). Inside "joe" I have my personal files. Outside "joe" but still in the partition, there is random stuff that doesn't really belong anywhere, or now useless programs that I had to install there because the main Windows partition ran out of space.

My question is: If during the Ubuntu installer I choose to use that partition as /home and make a user called "joe", will everything work fine? Is it better if I delete the extra stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend using an NTFS partition as your `/home` partition for Linux, it can cause a lot of problems and [is not recommended](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=901127).

If you want easy access to your Windows files, you can install via [Wubi](http://wubi-installer.org/). It will automatically mount your Windows files under `/host` and `/media`. If you'd like to copy your Windows documents over to your Ubuntu install, there is an option for that I believe in the Ubuntu installer.

Comment: Would it be okay to make home ext3 or 4 and make symlinks to the NTFS partition?

Comment: Yes, you can symlink to an NTFS partition from ext3 or 4.